# Retrieving the value of selectCount in jooq

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have some code that looks like this:

```
Record record = jooq
    .selectCount()
    .from(USERS)
    .fetchOne();
```

Currently I'm doing the following to get the count:

```
Integer count = (Integer) record.getValue(0);
```

But it seems like there must be a better solution (that's type-safe...since that's the whole point of using jooq).  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, for this particular query, there aren't many "better" ways to typesafely get the `count()` value. What you could do, to add type-safety, is this:

```
Field<Integer> f = count();
Integer count = jooq.
    .select(f) // Or selectCount(). Replaced it to illustrate the case
    .from(USERS)
    .fetchOne(f);
```

The problem is that most of the type information about the projection has been "lost" to the Java compiler, by the time the `fetch()` methods are "reached". There is no way that a `ResultQuery.fetchXXX()` method could recover it from the `SELECT` clause, and produce it to you.

On the jOOQ user group, some users have argued to move the projection into the `fetch()` methods, entirely, the way C#'s LINQ, or Scala's SLICK do it. This would greatly complicate the expression of more advanced `SELECT` statements. An [more elaborate explanation is documented here](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/select-lexical-vs-logical-order/).

With jOOQ 3.0, additional record-level typesafety has been introduced. In jOOQ 3.3, it will thus be possible to fetch a single value as such (has been registered as [#2246](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2246)):

```
<T> T fetchValue(Select<Record1<T>> select);
```